# Local repository for Nuget causing error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have come from the Maven world where for every project/solution you can read from a local repository (which could be updated from the public repository) and publish private code projects to the repository as well.

So, for example:

- I can get log4xxx from the public repository, but have only one local
  copy (per version) for all my projects.
- I could create, mycommoncode-1.1.0, from my
  project and it would land in the same directory
  (${user.home}/.m2/repository)

So in the same vein, I am trying to keep a local repository for my .NET projects by using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <packageSources>
    <!-- My specific and common packages can be sourced from this folder -->
    <add key="My Package Source" value="C:\sourcecode\CommonDLLs" />
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>

 ...

  <config>
    <!-- Install packages in this folder instead of default $(Solutiondir)\Packages -->
    <add key="repositorypath" value="C:\sourcecode\CommonDLLs" />
  </config>

</configuration>
```

To test this I packaged up an assembly, creating MyProject.dll.1.0.0.nupkg file for my project.

Then in Visual Studio, I selected another project and selected Manage NuGet Packages... I see MyProject.dll and an Install button.

But then I get errors:

```
'MyProject.dll 1.0.0' already installed.
Adding 'MyProject.dll 1.0.0' to MyTestProject.
Uninstalling 'MyProject.dll 1.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'MyProject.dll 1.0.0'.
**Failed to add reference to 'MyProject'.**
```

I think it has to do with the path for both package source and respositoryPath, but wanted to confirm. True? Why does this not work? In theory, then I would have a single local repository.

**Update**:
I tried making the config point to different directories. I still get the same errors.

So it must be how I build the local repository files and/or where they are located:

I have a dll, MyProject.dll:
Step 1: Run nuget command
    nuget spec MyProject.dll (which is in a folder 'lib')
Step 2: Edit nuget spec file
    edit .nuspec file created 
Step 3: Run nuget command
    nuget pack MyProject.nuspec

This leaves me with 3 items in my folder:
    MyProject.dll.nuspec
    lib/MyProject.dll
    MyProject.dll.1.0.0.nupkg

I tried just placing the .nupkg alone to the path pointed to by packageSources. Still same error.

Thanks a million!

**Update #2**:

Here is stack trace from running install in PM console:

```
PM> install-package -source c:\sourcecode\createcommon MyProject.dll
'MyProject.dll 1.0.0' already installed.
Adding 'MyProject.dll 1.0.0' to MyTestProject.
Uninstalling 'MyProject.dll 1.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'MyProject.dll 1.0.0'.
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'MyProject'.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  -source c:\sourcecode\createcommon MyProject.dll
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM> $error[0].Exception.StackTrace
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsProjectSystem.AddReference(String referencePath, Stream stream)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.ExtractPackageFilesToProject(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReferenceToProject(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute(PackageOperation operation)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute(IPackage package, IPackageOperationResolver resolver)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReference(IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.<>c__DisplayClass60.<AddPackageReference>b__5f()
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.RunProjectAction(IProjectManager projectManager, Action action)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.AddPackageReference(IProjectManager projectManager, IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.<>c__DisplayClass8.<InstallPackage>b__4()
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.RunSolutionAction(Action action)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.InstallPackage(IProjectManager projectManager, String packageId, SemanticVersion version, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean skipAssemblyReferences, ILogger logger)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.InstallPackage(IProjectManager projectManager, String packageId, SemanticVersion version, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, ILogger logger)
   at NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand.InstallPackage(IVsPackageManager packageManager)
   at NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand.ProcessRecordCore()
   at NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.NuGetBaseCommand.ProcessRecord()
PM>
```

Inner exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to add reference to 'Utility'. --->   
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at VSLangProj.References.Add(String bstrPath)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsProjectSystem.AddReference(String referencePath, Stream stream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: I would highly suggest downloading and running [ProGet][http://inedo.com/proget/download] for private Nuget repository.
With that being said, I have yet to successfully run all of my packages from the same directory. I've tried numerous times and always end up sticking with the default behavior.

Comment: The error message does not show the underlying exception. Can you run the package install from the PowerShell console and then look at the exception using something like `$error[0].Exception` or `$error[0].Exception.StackTrace`

Comment: Added stack trace for exception to question. Wonder why it says it already is installed??